# Outlook Add-ins OWA ios not loading

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I'm a little stump with what's wrong with my manifest that my add-in won't load on the web version of Outlook 365. It loads just fine on the native iOS outlook and on desktop web browsers in outlook.office365.com.  I followed the samples provided on how to Add MobileFormFactor, but can't get the icon to appear when I read an email.

My manifest validator says i'm ok so far.
[Manifest Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCgxT.png)

here is my manifest.

```
          <MobileFormFactor>

            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
            <Group id="mobileMsgRead">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="TaskPaneBtn">
                  <Label resid="restpaneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="mobile-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="mobile-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="mobile-32" />

                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="mobile-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="mobile-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="mobile-32" />

                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="mobile-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="mobile-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="mobile-32" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
             </Group>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </MobileFormFactor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following at the end of your `<Form>` element:

```
  <TabletSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://dev2.practicepanther.com/outlook" />
    <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
  </TabletSettings>
  <PhoneSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://dev2.practicepanther.com/outlook" />
  </PhoneSettings>
```

Does that help?

Comment: Yes it worked!! wish the documentation for mobile support addressed this. https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/mobileformfactor?product=outlook&version=v1.5